# How can I update the added pod file? Syntax Error

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

I added new frameworks in pod file then pod update command but got an syntax error (Invalid 'Podfile' file syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end)

Please see attached.

[image: Pod Update]

How does it works?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: try to create your podfile with `pod init`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `u` from `PubNub` version.

Comment: I see. Got it already, Thank you so much :)

Comment: No worries, If it is the right answer for you please mark it as right, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Got this, update all pods but when I checked the pod folder in xcode pubnub doesn't appear. How would I know if does it works? :)

Comment: Try removing `Podfile.lock` and `.xcworkspace` and run `pod install`

Comment: It works @SaintThread :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
terminal had pointed out your error, look at the yellow circle, it marks ">" to show the error line, and you should check syntax error of this line.
Clearly，"u" is redundant. Please remove it.

Comment: Got this already. Thank you :)